# Remote desktop slows down over time Win 10 to Win 7 but reconnecting makes normal again

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, performance, remote-desktop

EDIT Dec 2, 2015 - corrected question to state that it's Win 10 to Win 7, not Win 7 to Win 7.

When using remote desktop to connect from a Windows 10 computer to a Windows 7 computer, the speed of interacting slows down substantially within an hour of being connected and actively using it (doing anything becomes really sluggish).

Disconnecting and reconnecting makes the speed return to normal.

What could be causing this?

EDIT Dec 2, 2015:  Some more details are the computers aren't on the same network. Internet speed of computer connecting from is 50Mbps down / 5Mbps Up with speedtest from 3 different sites showing 56.27/6.65, 53.95/6.36, 60.53/7.08.  Internet speed of computer being connected to is 100M/20M.  The actions being performed through remote desktop are things like browsing the internet, using FTP, using a code editor, and maybe a few other things.

Comment: Need more info. Are the computers located on the same network? If outside of network, what's the internet speed at both ends? Wired or wireless? What actions are you performing on the computers?

Comment: @Papa updated the question

Comment: @sa298 wired or wifi?

Comment: @Papa - sorry, it's wireless on the connecting computer, and wired on the computer being connected to